# How to increase /root partition using GPARTED

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual boot Windows + Ubuntu machine. There is plenty of space in my `/home` partition and recently I got an error message showing that I have low disk space in `/root`. I want to resize my `/root` an put some of the space from `/home` into `/root`. Unfortunately I cannot find the `/root` in GParted.

Here is an image of the GParted screen.

[image: gparted]

Comment: Partition(s) are mounted, and you can't resize whilst mounted. The easiest way is by booting *live* media (such as Ubuntu install media) using the *Try Ubuntu* option and resize from there.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`, and tell me what version Ubuntu you're running, and I can make the best recommendation. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: You say that "unfortunately I cannot find the `/root` in GParted". The `/root` partition is the one called `/` in the Mount Point column.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: See also: [partitioning - How to modify partitions without a live USB/CD - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314402/how-to-modify-partitions-without-a-live-usb-cd)

Answer (score 1):

We'll convert your partition-based swap, to a /swapfile. We'll delete the swap partition, and use that unallocated space to increase the / partition. You'll need to have a bootable Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to proceed.

**Edit /etc/fstab...**

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

and comment out this line:

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx none  swap       sw       0       0
```

Save the edit and quit the editor

**Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB**

Start `gparted`.

Do a `swapoff` on the /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition

`Delete` the /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition, as it won't be used any more

`Drag` the right side of the /dev/nvme0n1p5 partition all the way right

Click the `Apply` button

Quit `gparted`

Reboot

**Create a /swapfile...**

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm xxG RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other uncommented “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

**Note**: Use SPACES, not TABS

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```