# Struggling to resize disk in Ubuntu VM

Tags: partitioning, gparted, vmware

I have an Ubuntu VM using VMware Fusion. It originally had 100 GB of hard disk space, which I increased to 120 GB following [Resizing a virtual disk in VMware Fusion (1020778)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1020778). This worked fine, but making the corresponding changes in Ubuntu has been far from trivial for me.

Attached are screenshots of GParted, `df -h` and `lvmdiskscan`:

[image: GParted]

[image: Output of df -h]

[image: Output of lvmdiskscan]

What I would like to do is add the unallocated 20 GB to my extended partition (specifically, `/dev/sda6`). I have also tried using KVPM and various approaches described here to no avail: [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume). I am unable to resize `sda6` or `sda2`. I can `swap-off` `sda5`, but I can't deactivate `sda6`.

How can I do this without a live CD? Note the red exclamation point wasn't there originally. I have since introduced it after several previous failed attempts.

Also, why does GParted show the 83 GB partition as fully used, but `df` shows that only 22 GB is in use?

Comment: I can provide more information if required.

Comment: The key icon indicates that the partition is mounted and cannot be operated on. If you for some reason cannot boot to a live environment to do the work, you might be able to unmount it and perform the operations in the session you are in.  But if it's your / partition, that will not work of course.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to unmount it, since it's my / partition. In which case, there's no way to do resizing (growing in this case) without a live cd?

Comment: Not at my level of knowledge.

Comment: You can use GParted without a live cd if you follow the process here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314402/how-to-modify-partitions-without-a-live-usb-cd

Comment: If this was Virtualbox you would just download the GParted iso, place it in the virtual CD drive and boot it. I’m not familiar with VMware fusion but I’d guess you can do something similar.

Comment: GParted is showing you that the entire sda6 is in use. It’s all allocated to your volume group. df -h is showing you that of the 83GB in the volume group only 22GB is in use to store files. You have 56GB available to hold more files, data, apps etc. If you try the lsblk command its output might help understand this.

Comment: To make use of your 20 GB unallocated space you could create a new partition, add it to your volume group and resize the filesystem. This is a good guide https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Comment: It is better to include the command outputs as *text*, rather than a screen shot, as it is not possible to search images, whereas text will show up in Google..