# Having issues with fixing /dev/sda2 recovering journal

Tags: partitioning, fsck, inode

Today I saw that Ubuntu was cleaning up orphaned inodes. Here's the boot log message:

```
/dev/sda2: clearing orphaned inode 396229 uid=1000 gid=1000 mode 0100600 ,si
/dev/sda2: clearing orphaned inode 1300596 uid=1000 gid=1000 mode 0100600 ,si
/dev/sda2: clean 578019/30049216 files, 22460578/121120000 blocks
```

Along with this:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent, instance -)
```

The boot then resumes.
I rebooted my system many times and the log varies.Sometimes the Postifix error never shows, sometimes it tells me I'm missing lowerdir, and sometimes it just shows me the first three lines above.Upon further investigation, I managed to pinpoint the errors to /dev/sda2, but I cant seem to tamper with it, even as superuser.After that I ran a partial fsck on the filesystem and it tells me this:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsk 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
Warning! /dev/sda2 is mounted,
\Warning : skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list is found. Fix? no

Inode 390774 was part of the orphaned inode list.   IGNORED.
Inode 390808 was part of the orphaned inode list.   IGNORED.
Deleted Inode 1300596 has zero dtime. Fix? no

Inode 2087213 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter. Optimize? no

Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(189466--189467) -(189956--189963) -(261644--261652)
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong (98659422, counted=98643826).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:    -390774  -390808  -1300596
Fix? no

/dev/sda2: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/sda2: 578019/30049216 files (0.8% non-contiguous), 22460578/121120000 blocks


At this point, I have tried to umount the filesystem  to actually fix the error, but it tells me it's busy, even though I ran the "kill all processes command".I also tried to do it through grub shell prompt, with no luck either.I may be forgetting something (I'm still a beginner), but I would like some help with fixing this filesystem
```

Also, I would prefer a method that does not require a live usb, simply because I dont have one, and It's pretty hard to get one in my area, but i am still open to all solutions.

Comment: Sorry About that last line on the code, I tried to space it out =(

Comment: If you keep having to run `fsck` and it keeps showing problems like orphaned inodes, this is indicative of drive failure. If your backups aren't in order, now is the time to make sure they are.

Comment: Also **don't run fsck on a mounted file system**.  You will break things. Get a USB, they are inexpensive and an invaluable tool for when you need to do things to your system without the installed system running. It also will allow you to reinstall the OS if necessary or if you have to replace the drive.

Comment: Alright.Thank you for the advice =) Is there anything else I need to be aware of? Ill be sure to order a USB and see what happens.Till then, what will I be locked out of? Will it be the entire disk or only files that has the corrupted/orphaned inodes? Also, I loaded the backup and I'm still getting the recovery log on boot.Thanks to everyone in advance =)

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? Have you installed a Windows driver that will allow you to read/write to Linux partitions?

Comment: You can boot into a live environment without a usb drive or optical drive using this approach https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314402/how-to-modify-partitions-without-a-live-usb-cd/1314403#1314403 I think the GParted iso would contain fsck but this approach works with many isos.

Comment: @GravvyBoiiz  Status please...

Comment: I managed to get a USB and mounted it, but I'm still  unable to unmount the files stem, asfor windows, I only emulated windows 7 through wine. I apologize  for a late response, been dealing with  college.

Answer (score 0):

The **proper** way to check/repair your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`