# resize root partition from rescue mode

Tags: partitioning, parted

I mean to resize my root partition.
I am currently not able to boot from a Live CD or Live USB.
I know I can keep trying to tackle that problem.

Alternatively, I wanted to know if, booting from my Ubuntu in recovery mode, dropping to a root prompt, using parted to resize, is expected to give me a resized, bootable partition.

I know it is a risky operation, I am not asking about that, and there is certainly no need for any warning or advice about backups.

I mean to know from the standpoint of how Ubuntu works, if the procedure should theoretically work (assuming there are no power shortages or other events that make the risks come true).
I am not sure if this opens files in a way that it is impossible to achieve what I mean in this way.

Comment: I don’t think so (I just don’t think parted will let you adjust the mounted root partition) - but if you’ve taken all the backup precautions you mention, why not try and post the answer so we’ll all know for sure?!

Comment: You can boot into GParted with no CD/DVD/USB by using the procedure described here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314402/how-to-modify-partitions-without-a-live-usb-cd/1314403#1314403

Comment: @PonJar - This looks very much useful for my needs. I will read it in detail, try a few things, and post feedback. Thanks.