# Boot live .squashfs image from partition

Tags: boot, live-usb, live-cd, initramfs

Previously on Debian Jesse on Raspberry PI, I did a solution that was booting the system from one of squasefs images and overlayfs in the second partition (and alternatively boot to "main" system inf boot from the image wasn't successful). That worked quite ok.

Now I'm trying to do the same functionality on Ubuntu Focal. I did come across information about the Ubuntu Live system, but I'm stuck with a lack of information and examples. Maybe I'm just not looking in the right places. One of the different thing is that with Ubuntu there is an uBoot config, that I didn't have any experience before today.

Is there available more information or examples on how to define where I can load sqashfs image? In my old solution, I did a small initramfs script, that mounted partition with images into /run/images, remount squashfs image as the new root partition, setup overlayfs, update /ets/fstab on suqshfs overlay filesystem and continue boot into "new" system.

I think that Ubuntu Live is doing most of those things, however, I can't figure out how to actually set and boot into squashfs system. Am I wrong in my assumptions?

I will be very happy for any pointer to documentation or maybe an example.

Best regards
Uros

Comment: Would a persistent live Ubuntu system do what you want? In that case, you can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create it. mkusb is focusing on PC computers, and the Ubuntu iso files for such computers. I think most systems for RPi are distributed as compressed image files, that are extracted into 'installed systems', not live or persistent live systems.

Comment: It is required to be a live and non-persistent system. It is a minimal system running one app. Its intention is about updating this app,  a matter of downloading an image and rebooting into the new image. And it is possible to switch images few times a day.

Comment: I asked and answered my own question about booting a GParted iso from disk here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314402/how-to-modify-partitions-without-a-live-usb-cd  It may contain something that will help you.

Comment: You can create your own live system (and own iso file). It might be complicated, but there are some tools for it, that might work, for example Cubic.